# InstallUtil which framework version was used to install service?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

Scenario: older 2.0 windows services installed on a server but if I try to use the newer 4.5 InstallUtil to uninstall I am getting an error.

We use an application that uses the InstallUtil service to uninstall/install windows services. Is there any way to check which framework version of InstallUtil was used to install the service? So that depending on which version was used I can pass the correct InstallUtil Path to the method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of InstallUtil try using Windows own SC.EXE

E.g. to uninstall service:

```
NET stop "Your Service Name"
SC delete "Your Service Name"
```

(first command used to stop service if it's still running)

Similarly you can use SC.EXE to create and start service. This way you're not depending on InstallUtil or its specific version.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the use of InstalUtil is extensive throughout the application

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the details I want using this code:

```
const string dotNetFourPath = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\EventLog\\Application\\" + "servicename "; //servicename here
using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(dotNetFourPath))
{
    Console.WriteLine(registryKey.GetValue("EventMessageFile")); //returns EventMessageFile - Value Data
}
```